# Create a SQL query to populate complex JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this model in the database:

```
create table collections (
    id serial primary key NOT null,
        title varchar (20) unique not null,
        group_id int[],
        publication_date timestamp not null,
    created_at timestamp NOT null default now(), 
    updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
    created_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL,
    updated_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL  
    );

insert into collections(title, group_id, publication_date, created_by, updated_by)
values 
('verano', '{1,2}',  now(),  1, 1),
('premium', '{2}', now(), 1, 1),
('moda 2023','{3}', now(), 1, 1),
('moda 2024','{4}', now(), 1, 1);

create table "groups" (
    id serial primary key NOT null,
        title varchar (50) unique not null,
        items_id int[],
        price float8 not null,
    description varchar (250),
    created_at timestamp NOT null default now(), 
    updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
        created_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL,
    updated_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL  
);

insert into "groups"(title, items_id, price, description ,created_by, updated_by)
values 
('Blusa De Dama Mikey Mouse', '{1,2}', 5.99,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Sueter Tricolor', '{3,4}', 13.85,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Mono Adidas', '{5,6}', 17.99,'Blusa de dama con micro durazno, distintos colores.' , 1, 1),
('Franela Apolo', '{}', 8.99,'Franela Apolo, distintos colores.' , 1, 1);

create table items (
  id serial primary key NOT null,
  "size" char not null,
  color varchar (10) not null,
  quantity int not null,
  images text[] not null,
  created_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
  updated_at timestamp NOT null default now(),
  created_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL,
  updated_by int references owners (id) NOT NULL
  );

insert into items (size, color, quantity, images, created_by, updated_by) 
values 
('U', 'Negro', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('S', 'Blanco', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('M', 'Gris', 150, '{none}', 1, 1),
('U', 'Gris', 220, '{none}', 1, 1),
('S', 'Verde', 220, '{none}', 1, 1),
('M', 'Negro', 220, '{none}', 1, 1);
```

I tried to do this test with this query and it brings me the title of the group to which the ID that I am querying in position 1 of the array belongs to.

`select c.title, (select g.title as title_g from "groups" g where c.group_id[1]  = g.id) from collections c;`

But I can't find a way to go through the group_id array so that it brings me all the records dynamically.

According to this model and these insertions, I need to make a query that gives me the following result.

```
"products":[{
    "Verano":
        [{
        "ID": "1asd6ada",
            "title": "Blusa De Damas"
        "price" 5.99,
            "description": "Descripcion general del grupo",
        "items": [{
                "ID":"1asd6ada",
                "size":"SS",
                "color":"Roja"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}},   
                {
                "ID":"1asda",
                "size":"M",
                "color":"Azul"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}}]
                },
        {
        "ID": "1asd6ada",
            "title": "Sueter Tricolor"
        "price" 10.5,
            "description": "Descripcion general del grupo",
        "items": [{
                "ID":"1asd6ada",
                "size":"SS",
                "color":"Roja"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}},   
                {
                "ID":"1asda",
                "size":"M",
                "color":"Azul"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}}]
                }]
        
        },
        {
        "Premium":
        [{
        "ID": "1asd6ada",
            "title": "Franela Jersey"
        "price" 16.99,
            "description": "Descripcion general del grupo",
        "items": [{
                "ID":"1asd6ada",
                "size":"SS",
                "color":"Roja"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}},   
                {
                "ID":"1asda",
                "size":"M",
                "color":"Azul"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}}]
                },
        {
        "ID": "1asd6ada",
            "title": "Jean Vaqueros"
        "price" 8.60,
            "description": "Descripcion general del grupo",
        "items": [{
                "ID":"1asd6ada",
                "size":"SS",
                "color":"Roja"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}},   
                {
                "ID":"1asda",
                "size":"M",
                "color":"Azul"  
                "images":{"image_one", "image_two"}}]
                }]
        
        }]
```

Basically it would be that in the Gruop_ID field of the Collections table I replace the ID's of the groups with all the information from that Group table, and in the Items_ID field of the group table, I replace those ID's with the values ​​of the table Items corresponding to that specific group.

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write

Comment: You might find this useful: [Postgres: JOIN on an array field](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/postgres-join-on-an-array-field/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_agg is what you need:

```
select json_build_object('products', json_agg(col.products))
from (select json_build_object(c.title,
                               (select json_agg(g2.*)
                                from (select g.id,
                                             g.title,
                                             g.price,
                                             (select json_agg(items.*)
                                              from (select id, size, color, quantity, images
                                                    from items t
                                                    where t.id = any (g.items_id)) items) as items
                                      from "groups" g
                                      where g.id = any (c.group_id)) g2)) products
      from collections c) col;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9-6Qx2xF)

EDIT: Updated as per your comment:

```
select c.id,
       c.title,
       jsonb_pretty(
               (select json_agg(g2.*)
                from (select g.id,
                             g.title,
                             g.price,
                             (select json_agg(items.*)
                              from (select id, size, color, quantity, images
                                    from items t
                                    where t.id = any (g.items_id)) items) as items
                      from "groups" g
                      where g.id = any (c.group_id)) g2)::jsonb) products
from collections c;
```

| id | title | products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | verano | [ { "id": 1, "items": [ { "id": 1, "size": "U", "color": "Negro", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 150 }, { "id": 2, "size": "S", "color": "Blanco", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 150 } ], "price": 5.99, "title": "Blusa De Dama Mikey Mouse" }, { "id": 2, "items": [ { "id": 3, "size": "M", "color": "Gris", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 150 }, { "id": 4, "size": "U", "color": "Gris", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 220 } ], "price": 13.85, "title": "Sueter Tricolor" } ] |
| 2 | premium | [ { "id": 2, "items": [ { "id": 3, "size": "M", "color": "Gris", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 150 }, { "id": 4, "size": "U", "color": "Gris", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 220 } ], "price": 13.85, "title": "Sueter Tricolor" } ] |
| 3 | moda 2023 | [ { "id": 3, "items": [ { "id": 5, "size": "S", "color": "Verde", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 220 }, { "id": 6, "size": "M", "color": "Negro", "images": [ "none" ], "quantity": 220 } ], "price": 17.99, "title": "Mono Adidas" } ] |
| 4 | moda 2024 | [ { "id": 4, "items": null, "price": 8.99, "title": "Franela Apolo" } ] |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gctezDIH)

Comment: It is exactly the expected result, but I need to do it as a table to be able to obtain it in a backend, that is, in the first column there must be the title of the collection, and in the second column, an array with all the groups corresponding to that collection , and likewise, within each group, an array with each item corresponding to that group.

Comment: @NeiferReverón, updated to reflect that. Wish you had that as desired output in your original question. You were asking the previous one.